# How to Map and Filter in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
carModel:
          [
           {_id : A, title : 2012},
           {_id : B, title : 2014}
          ],

car:      [{
            color    :'red',
            carModel : B //mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
           },
           {
            color    :'black',
            carModel : B //mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
           }     
          ]
```

Here i add carModel ID on car's carModel and trying to filter on my react page

```
car.map(item=> 
              <p>{item.color}</p>
              <p>{carModel.map(model=> model.filter(model._id == item.carModel ? model.title : null)}
       )
```

I want to show carModel on page, here above code is not working and i believe this is not an exact method to do this, please rectify me

Comment: you need to `return` your elements from `map`

Comment: could you please explain

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
car.map(item=> {
  const filteredModels = carModel.filter(model => model._id === item.carModel);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{item.color}</p>
      {filteredModels.map(model => <p>{model.title}</p>)}
    </div>
  );      
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` your elements like this to make it work. Also wrapping your elements with a `div` or something

```
car.map(item=> 
  return (<div>
    <p>{item.color}</p>
    <p>{carModel.map(model=> model.filter(model._id == item.carModel ? model.title : null)}
   </div>)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

filter method callback parameter is a function and you need to return one element in map function, so;

```
car.map(item=> {
  return (<div>
    <p>{item.color}</p>
      {carModel.filter(model => model._id === item.carModel).map(model => <p>{model.title}</p>)}
  </div>);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
car.map(item=> {
  return (
    <p>{item.color}</p>
    {
      carModel.filter(model => model._id === item.carModel)
      .map(m => <p>{m.title}</p>)
    }
  );      
})
```